# how to write filter conf file in logstash to read myCustomLogFile with "|" seprator and key=value

Tags: logstash

my logfile look like this:

```
loc=846|time=2012-12-18 12:59:36|action=drop|orig=129.3.70.1|i/f_dir=inbound|i/f_name=eth1|has_accounting=0|uuid=<00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000>|product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1|__policy_id_tag=product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1[db_tag={8831AF0A-6B32-11E3-869E-000000000D0D};mgmt=sc-tog;date=1387735052;policy_name=Standard]|src=192.168.100.2|s_port=60184|dst=198.41.0.4|service=53|proto=udp|rule=15
```

i want that this log will be sperated to key value json for save it in elasticsearch.
i am using logstash and i have the logs in a file
the sperator is "|" charcter

i dont know how to write the filter in the logstash conf file for read this log
how the conf file for the logstash shold be look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [kv filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/kv):

```
filter {
  kv {
    field_split => "|"
  }
}
```

You probably want to remove the `message` field if the key/value split is successful, plus you'll want to parse the timestamp in the `time` field with the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date):

```
filter {
  kv {
    field_split => "|"
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["time", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    remove_field => ["time"]
  }
}
```

You'll probably also want to convert some of the fields from string fields to integer fields. Tack on a [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) for that.

```
mutate {
  convert => {
    "loc" => "integer"
    "rule" => "integer"
    "s_port" => "integer"
    "service" => "integer"
  }
}
```

Comment: this exactly what i wanted and you also gave me bonus here with your answer. Magnux Back ... you make my day :)